# how to use emailext-template in jenkins pipeline to get the template?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

There is a good plugin, [emailext-template](https://plugins.jenkins.io/emailext-template/). Basically, I do not have the access to Jenkins-server. It is not convenient to choose the option mentioned in [emailext](https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/#groovy-script-content-templates) to create the email template.

I dont know how to use this [emailext-template](https://plugins.jenkins.io/emailext-template/) plugin to get the template in jenkins-pipeline. There is no guideline in [emailext-template](https://plugins.jenkins.io/emailext-template/). Any documents?

```
// expected usage in jenkins-pipeline
template_str = emailext-template('template-id')
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the following way, In case you can deploy jenkins again (if it is done on the cloud), you could create and deploy your email template as part of jenkins installation and configuration.

In case you did not have access to the jenkins server even while deployment, you can just form the html template with the corresponding variables and then use them in the job configuration itself.

The below image shows how the template files are used in jenkins, Instead of the script tag as in the image, you can replace with your own html content so that jenkins will be able to send email with that content.

[image: Jenkins email template or content configuration]

Comment: I agree with this. In other words, I need to create a new jenkin-job for my pipeline to store the email-template string. Basically, the email-template string in the jenkins-pipeline script is quite long.

Comment: you can create another job with the email content templates and after this job is completed, in the post build step, you can invoke the email job that can send the email.